# Edimax EW-7822ULC wifi adapter driver installation

Tags: drivers, wireless, ubuntu-mate

How do I install the wifi driver for the [Edimax EW-7822ULC](http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_ac1200_dual-band/ew-7822ulc/) (wifi-adapter).

It's a zip file and I don't know how to compile and install it.

I run Ubuntu MATE 16.04 with kernel 4.10.0-40 and all the latest updates.

Comment: did you already take a look on this thread? https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000065859-how-to-install-ew-7822ulc-in-linux-running-kernel-higher-than-v4-11

Comment: sorry yes i know that full page. i tried using that thread for fedora but other problems were occuring. i didn't read the full page.  i'm trying it right now

Comment: ok please take a look and try it let me know the result

Comment: yep it worked. i did the all the steps except the git clone step since i am not running a kernel newer than 4.11. thanks

Comment: Would you please consider writing an answer with the steps you did to help others?